# Angular table rendering problem(it renders too much cells)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have 3 arrays of data. For clarity - arrays are called `DATA_CENT`, `DATA_NORTH` and `DATA_WEST`. Each of them includes another array called data. I need to extract this data array to my table.

As you can see, for each new big column I create new table. Then I need to extract data to each of that columns.

```
<table *ngFor="let elem of COLUMN_NAMES">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" class="top">{{elem}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="top-1">all</th>
            <th class="top-1">done</th>
            <th class="top-1">ctrl</th>
            <th class="top-1">rjct</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tbody *ngIf="showcent">
        <tr *ngFor="let comp of elem.data">
            // Here I need to render DATA_CENT.data information
            <td>{{comp.all}}</td>
            <td>{{comp.done}}</td>
            <td>{{comp.ctrl}}</td>
            <td>{{comp.rjct}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tbody *ngIf="shownorth">
        <tr *ngFor="let comp of elem1.data">
            // DATA_NORTH info
            <td>{{comp.all}}</td>
            <td>{{comp.done}}</td>
            <td>{{comp.ctrl}}</td>
            <td>{{comp.rjct}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tbody *ngIf="showwest">
        <ng-container>
            <tr *ngFor="let comp of elem1.data">
                //DATA_WEST info
                <td>{{comp.all}}</td>
                <td>{{comp.done}}</td>
                <td>{{comp.ctrl}}</td>
                <td>{{comp.rjct}}</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm having troubles with rendering that table. I can't place loops right - sometimes there is too many of cells, sometimes they are not fit in table.

Here is how the table looks like: 
[image: table overview]

PS (for better understanding): First 3 cells in first column are buttons. When I click them, data, associated with that button, folds/unfolds.

Here is GitHub of the project, if needed: https://github.com/kulaska/Table-app/tree/table_el_toggle_branch

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing what the problem is. I've created a minimal SlackBlitz for you [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sof-kulaska) to help you explain your problem.

Comment: I made some changes in file. Check it, please. I hope I gave you a better vision of my problem.
Here is my app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/sof-kulaska-8jfh4c
All comments are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is due to not iterating through the `data` array.

Instead of:

```
<td>{{comp.data.all}}</td>
```

You need to have

```
<td>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of comp.data">
        <td>{{data.all}}</td>
    </tr>
</td>
```

Or something similar but you need to loop through the `data` array.

Comment: I know that's dumb, but still, I can't make it work.
I understood what you said, but I cant loop through the object in a right way. I can't explicitly set "for loop".
https://stackblitz.com/edit/sof-kulaska-8jfh4c - here is the app.
Look at the place with tbody *ngIf="shownorth", please. It almost renders right in the table, but instead of DATA_NORTH[0] there should be DATA_NORTH[i] with i pointing on the position of object in the array.
Can I somehow solve that?
I'd really, really appreciate your help on that

Comment: I see what your issue is. Your problem is the structure of your table and html, as you need to inversely iterate through your array . You can do a quick (but slightly hacky fix) by iterating through a list of numbers and using that as `i`. Take a look at [this] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/sof-kulaska-xchxjn) for the `*ngIf="shownorth"` section.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, that helped.
The only thing I replaced was explicit number of rows you written. I changed it to  
dataCountN = Array(this.DATA_NORTH[0].data.length).fill(0).map((x,i)=>i);